# why is my code output 0 when i did the syntax correctly

Tags: c++, stdio, nested-if

I think the problem starts before the nested if because at the end of the code it should output the result of `sales = price * sold`, but it also output 0

```
#include<stdio.h>
main() {
    int num, price, sold, sales;
    float compercent, commision;
    printf("Enter Unit Price: ");
    scanf("%d", &price);
    printf("Enter Quantity Sold: ");
    scanf("%d", &sold);
    sales = price * sold;

    if (sales >= 50000) {
        compercent = 0.1;
    }
    else if (sales >= 40000 && sales < 50000) {
        compercent = 0.08;
    }
    else if (sales >= 30000 && sales < 40000) {
        compercent = 0.06;
    }
    else if (sales >= 20000 && sales < 30000) {
        compercent = 0.04;
    }
    else if (sales >= 10000 && sales < 20000) {
        compercent = 0.02;
    }
    else if (sales >= 5000 && sales < 10000) {
        compercent = 0.01;
    }
    else if(sales<5000){
        compercent = 0;
    }
    commision = sales * compercent;
    printf("Sales: ");
    printf("sales = %f", &sales);
    printf("Commision: ");
    printf("%f", &commision);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use `prinf` you don't need to provide the variable as references. The function expects an integers or float, not a pointer.

This should fix it:

```
printf("sales = %i\n", sales);
printf("Commision: ");
printf("%f", commision);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use '&' to print a variable value in printf statement. It will generally print some  garbage value (or 0, as in your case).
I think this should fix your problem:

```
printf("Sales: ");
printf("sales = %f", sales);
printf("Commision: ");
printf("%f", commision);
```